# Why can't I use BuildContext after await in an async function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've updated my Dart linter today and was informed of the changes in the Problems tab in VSCode. Turns out I've been doing many unrecommended operations in my work.

Here is a snippet of code I have among many that has the same order of operations:

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CheckoutScreenState>(
      builder: (context, state, _) {
        return CustomFooter(
          total: 'Php ${state.totalAmount}',
          inAsync: state.inAsync,
          onPressed: state.isReady()
              ? () async {
                  await state.postCheckout();
                  String? storeName = await SecureStorage.instance.read(
                    key: 'storeName',
                  );

                  if (state.orderDetails != null) {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(
                      context,
                      OrderReceipt.id,
                      arguments: {
                        'state': state,
                        'storeName': storeName,
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (_) {
                        return CustomAlert(
                          headingText: 'Error',
                          subText:
                              'An error occurred while processing your order. Please try again.',
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                }
              : () {},
          buttonColor: state.isReady() ? kPrimaryColor : kFieldHintTextColor,
          buttonText: 'Place Order',
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I'm just wondering what rule I'm violating and if it's so vital for me to change my code. So far I haven't had problems with it but the linter advises otherwise. What is wrong by having accessed the context after an asynchronous gap.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful video by the Flutter team was apparently posted one month after posting my question. To summarize, the widget's corresponding element has unpredictable moments in which it would refresh, causing the BuildContext to change.

The `BuildContext` in this case being the widget's element. The following is the Flutter team's explanation about it.

> The more dramatically your widget tree changes from one frame to the next, the more likely Flutter is in need to update portions of your element tree. And for every new frame, it's always possible that a given widget's element has been removed from the tree. Unpredictable events from your user can force Flutter to reassemble the element tree at any moment. So, the only safe way to build your widget is to avoid asynchronous usage of a `BuildContext`.

More information in the link below:

https://youtu.be/bzWaMpD1LHY

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).